# Are there any C++ libraries for real-time animation of a 3D model using changing x,y coordinates of feature key points

Tags: animation, 3d, real-time, kinect

I am working on a project where I am to use the Kinect to track facial expressions and animate a 3D model (.ply) accordingly.

So far I have managed to track a human face with a finite number of key-points on the face. I am able to get the coordinates of each key-point at every frame.

I am not very adept with animating techniques and general concepts of Mesh deformation and would really appreciate if one could provide a library which provides a high-level API so as to do said animation using x,y coordinates of key-points.

I am aware of CUBICA but unsure whether it can be used for what I want. Please excuse me as I am not very adept with this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am trying to do a very similar thing

Answer (score 0):

I too am looking for something that would do this (with .NET if possible), so I could hook Kinect up, set the position of each joint and see the character animate - without needing to set the position and angle of each bone which quickly gets very complex when you take into account the X,Y and Z positions.

So far my research has lead me to believe I will need a 3D engine that supports [inverse kinematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics)  - if anyone else had any better advice I'd be keen to hear it.